# SQL Get records from Parent where Parent Table have Relation and have Common Item With Other parents

Tags: sql-server, database

I have three tables 
**Company**   , **Vehicles**, **Relationships**
In company Table there are two columns one is Company ID and the second is Company name and data is like this

```
ID               CompanyName

101              CompanyOne
102              companyTwo
103              CompanyThree
```

In Vehicles tables there are three columns

```
    ID                          CompnayID                                     Vehicle 
   001                            101-                                          BUS
   002                            102                                           BUS
   003                            103                                          Truck 
   004                            103                                          Cycle 
   005                            104                                           Bike
   006                            102                                          Truck
   007                            101                                          truck
```

In Table Relations there are  4 columns

```
 RelationshipID    CompanyOneID       Relationship Name    CompanyTwoID
  1                     101            Collaborate              102
  2                     102            Collaborate              101
  3                     104            Collaborate              102
  4                     103            Collaborate              104
```

Now what I want is, To have all those companies name and Vehicles Name  , Where Companies **have “Collaboration” Relationship** (There may be other types of relationships too) and **have Common Vehicles Names** , I also want to have single record  like   Company 101 have Relationship with 102 and have Common Vehicles  and similarly company 102 also have been mention in the relation table to have relationship with the company 101  , here I only Want One Match Either Company 101 To company 102 or Company 102 to company 101 .

e.g 
Result will be

```
CompanyOne                  CompanyTwo                 Vehicle 
101                          102                        BUS
101                          102                        Truck
```

Note:- Company 104 have collaboration with some other Companies but they don’t have common Vehicles 
And Company 103 have common vehicles but they don’t collaborate  with the same company with whom it have collaboration that why I don’t want to select it.

I am using SQL SERVER

Comment: Don't just post a question to stackoverflow without showing some minimum effort that you have tried to solve the problem yourself. We're not here to do your job for you. Show us some code, what have you tried so far? What output did you get or what error messages did you get?

Comment: I think the way i have  expressed my problem ..is showing that i am putting my effort. .and further more if had any idea how to solve i had not posted here..  .

Comment: I'm just asking for one or two sample SELECT queries that shows, that you have actually tried to combine the data in the tables. You would be surprised by how far you get, once you actually sit down and try to code the solution to your problem. If you don't know how to write any SQL at all, you should read up on it, and then get back to us when you have a particular problem with the code.

Comment: Just a Quick Thought ...You think that it can't be done using SQL then i may Go for C# .. but this is too bad instead of helping,  you are saying this,,,,i am writing different queries from previous two days ... the problem is that i am not so expert in SQL , i have tried self joins , sub-queries  but nothing produced that is related to my problem and further more i have looked nearly all question posted here.

Comment: It can definitely be done using SQL. All I'm asking for is that you show us some of the code you have tried - and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Ok ... they table that i mentioned here are not real table the real quiries that i have written .. . Here you can look into it : 
SELECT   t_c.Start_Object_ID As 'Source Object ID',  t_o.Name as 'Source Name' ,
t_c.End_Object_ID as 'Destination Object ID', t_02.Name as DestinationName, t_c.Direction,  
t_operation.Name as OperationName
FROM t_object t_o CROSS JOIN t_connector t_c , t_object t_02 ,t_operation
WHERE ((t_c.Start_Object_ID = t_o.Object_ID)  
  AND (t_c.Connector_Type = 'Association'))  AND ((t_c.End_Object_ID = t_02.Object_ID))

Comment: Real situation is so complicated  and it would have took two to three pages to first wrote the context so, i simply posted idea here so that i could get an idea to solve my problem, thats all .

Answer (score 0):

A simple query like below should do what you want:

```
SELECT CompanyOneID, CompanyTwoId, V1.Vehicle
FROM Relationsships
INNER JOIN Vehicles V1 ON V1.CompanyId = CompanyOneID
INNER JOIN Vehicles V2 ON V2.CompanyId = CompanyTwoID
WHERE [Relationsship Name] = 'Collaborate' AND V1.Vehicle = V2.Vehicle
```

If company 1 is related to company 2 and vice versa, and you only want to show each relation once, you will need something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN CompanyOneID < CompanyTwoID THEN CompanyOneID ELSE CompanyTwoID END,
    CASE WHEN CompanyOneID > CompanyTwoID THEN CompanyOneID ELSE CompanyTwoID END,
    V1.Vehicle
FROM . . .    /* Rest of the query exactly the same as above */
```

Comment: Thanks i will apply this idea and will inform soon .. well thanks ..  and  sorry , i tried to keep question simple, thats why maybe i was not able to post a good question, anyways ..i only post here when i stuck, otherwise i know.. everyone's time is precious ..and thanks again .

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I was just trying to tell you that a question on stackoverflow gets answered a lot faster, if you show us some code. We get a lot of "do my homework"-style questions here, so a good question should always show some effort, preferably by posting the code they have tried so far (or just some similar, simplified code).

Comment: Thanks ..i will keep in mind next time will defiantly post Code with my question next time.